# Updating SKPhysicsBody rectangleOfSize

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So i have a paddle/bar, when that bar collides with a ball, it shrinks. I also want to update to SKPhysicsBody of the paddle/bar so that it keeps the same collisionbox as the visual sprite. How do I accomplish this?

Here is my current code, located inside an didBeginContact-collision function

```
bar.size = CGSizeMake(16 * playerLife, 16)
bar.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 16 * playerLife, height: 64))
```

The bar.size works as intended. physicsBody rectangleOfSize makes the game crash.

Update: included more code in response to comment

```
bar.size = CGSizeMake(16 * playerLife, 16)
bar.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 16 * playerLife, height: 64))


func CollisionWithDeathBar(ball: SKSpriteNode, deathBar: SKSpriteNode) {
    playerLife--
    bar.size = CGSizeMake(16 * playerLife, 16)
    shouldResizePaddle = true
}

override func didSimulatePhysics() {
    if shouldResizePaddle {
        bar.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 16 * playerLife, height: 64))
        shouldResizePaddle = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifying physics bodies during a physics contact callback is not allowed.

(Think about it. During an update to the physics simulation, SpriteKit has to examine all the physics bodies in the world, find collisions, and call contact handlers for each of them. If you could change the bodies in the midst of all that, you'd have undefined, or at least ill-defined, results.)

I'd recommend using the contact function to schedule a change of physics body to happen later. Something like this:

```
var shouldResizePaddle = false

func didBeginContact(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if /* paddle/ball contact */ {
        shouldResizePaddle = true
    }
}

override func didSimulatePhysics() {
    if shouldResizePaddle {
        bar.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 16 * playerLife, height: 64))
        shouldResizePaddle = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my post to include some more code. I tried your example, i get a weird problem. The paddle/bar (on collision) jumps down approx 32 pixels. And allows all balls to go right through it. It seems like the SKPhysicsBody simply disappears. It also crashes (sometimes) "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: It's not possible to diagnose all of those problems from the code you've posted. However, at least some are clear: if you re-create a physics body, you'll need to re-setup all attributes associated with it (like collision masks).

Comment: That was exactly what was missing, thanks! I didn't realise that it got re-created. I thought it just changed that value, similar to updating a variable. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help! When you see an expression like `bar.physicsBody = //...`, it always *replaces* the thing on the left with the thing on the right. When you see something like `Thing(/*...*/)`, it always *creates a new* `Thing`, regardless of what might be on the left in any expression it's in.